# C - My code works in one file but not another

Tags: c

I have a function that shuffles the elements of an array (possible duplicates). My code for the function is below:

```
int shuffle_values(int *array, int max_value){
  int i, j;
  int new_array[MAX_VALUE_ALLOWED];

  for (i = 0; i < max_value; ++i){
    new_array[i] = array[i];
  } 
  if (max_value > MAX_VALUE_ALLOWED){
    return 0;
  }else{
    for (j = 0; j < max_value; ++j){
      array[j] = new_array[(random_value(max_value) - 1)];
    }
   }return 1; 
}
```

Here is the code that tests my functions:

```
#define MAX_VALUE_ALLOWED 200

int random_value(int max_value){
  int rand_val;
  rand_val = (rand() % max_value) + 1;

  return rand_val;
}

void print_values(int *array, int max_value){
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < max_value; ++i){
    printf("%d|", array[i]);
  } printf("\n");
}

int main() {
   unsigned int seed = 20;
   int values[MAX_VALUE_ALLOWED], max_value;
   srand(seed);

   max_value = 8;
   shuffle_values(values, max_value);
   print_values(values, max_value);

   shuffle_values(values, max_value);
   print_values(values, max_value);

   max_value = 20;
   shuffle_values(values, max_value);
   print_values(values, max_value);

   shuffle_values(values, max_value);
   print_values(values, max_value);

   return 0;
}
```

The expected output is:

```
5|4|3|1|8|6|7|2|
3|4|7|5|8|2|1|6|
11|7|20|4|9|19|13|12|10|14|6|2|16|1|15|5|8|18|17|3|
6|3|5|9|14|15|20|2|10|11|16|8|7|17|1|19|18|12|4|13|
```

But I'm getting:

```
32517|-940709567|0|32517|0|0|-938539808|0|
32517|-940709567|-938539808|0|0|-940709567|32517|-940709567|
-940709567|-940709567|32517|32517|-940709567|0|-940709567|0|32767|32767|32517|0|1|0|0|32517|1|0|-940709567|0|
0|-940709567|-940709567|32767|0|0|1|-940709567|32517|32767|32767|-940709567|32517|-940709567|-940709567|1|0|0|32517|-940709567|
```

However when I test the same code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_VALUE_ALLOWED 200

int random_value(int max_value){
  int rand_val;
  rand_val = (rand() % max_value) + 1;

  return rand_val;
}

int main(){
  int max_value = 8;
  int array[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

  int i, m;
  printf("Original array:");
  for (i = 0; i < max_value; ++i){
  printf("%d|", array[i]);
  }printf("\n");

  printf("Shuffled array:");
  shuffle_values(array, max_value);
  for (m = 0; m < max_value; ++m){
  printf("%d|", array[m]);
  }printf("\n"); 
   return 0;
}
```

The output I get is correct:

```
Original array:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|
Shuffled array:8|7|2|4|2|8|3|5|
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: where do you assign values to `values` array in first example?

Comment: You seem to assume that any n successive calls to `random_value(n)` will return all values from 0 to n-1 in some order. Random number generators don't work this way.

Comment: OT: the check `if(max_value>MAX_VALUE_ALLOWED)` needs to be done *before* the first `for` loop in `shuffle_values`. Otherwise, you could have a buffer overrun before the `if` statement is reached.

Comment: No, there can be duplicate values once my array has been shuffled. (edit: I was replying to n.m.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have random values left in memory for your values array in main. It is working the way it's supposed to. However, you are using it on the data you don't want to work on.

Try initializing your values array before shuffling. Eg.:

```
for (i = 0; i < max_value; ++i){
    array[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: I'm actually not allowed to modify main, just the functions above it. Can I initialize the values inside the shuffle function?

Comment: @OlivierToujas Yes, you can initialize them in the function, or better yet, create a separate function just for initialization. Pass that array there.